# Trying to verify credit card number but showing a TypeError

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging

I have a feeling that I'm getting '**TypeError: cardLogo.setAttribute is not a function'** because I'm using the 'document.getElementsByClassName' instead of 'document.getElementsById'. Could that be the reason for my error or is there something else I'm missing?

What I want it to do is that when a number is inputted it verifies the card type (visa, mastercard, etc.) but I keep getting this error.

```
var cardNumber = new Cleave('.card-number-input', {
    creditCard: true,
    delimiter: " ",
    onCreditCardTypeChanged: function (type) {
        const cardLogo = document.getElementsByClassName('front-logo'),
        visa = 'fa-brands fa-cc-visa';


        switch (type) {
            case "visa":
                cardLogo.setAttribute("class", visa);
                break;
        
            default: 
            cardLogo.setAttribute("class", ' ');
            break;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: What does this have to do with reactjs. Because if you are using react, getElementsByClassName is *always* a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

The reason error is because `getElementsByClassName()` is return array of object, instead of object. So the best solutions you can try these code

```
var cardNumber = new Cleave('.card-number-input', {
    creditCard: true,
    delimiter: " ",
    onCreditCardTypeChanged: function (type) {
        const cardLogo = document.getElementsByClassName('front-logo'),
        visa = 'fa-brands fa-cc-visa';

        switch (type) {
            case "visa":
                cardLogo[0].setAttribute("class", visa);
                break;
        
            default: 
            cardLogo[0].setAttribute("class", ' ');
            break;
        }
    }
});
```

Also you can use `foreach` if you want.
But for this fast solustion adding `[0]` at the front of `cardLogo` is enough.